# Linq to SQL Nested IN FROM query

Tags: linq-to-sql

Can anyone tell me how to write a nested SQL query like

SELECT * FROM X WHERE X.ID IN (SELECT Y.XID FROM Y WHERE .....)

in LINQ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try:

```
var yIds = from y in dataContext.Y
           where ...
           select y.XId;

var query = from x in dataContext.X
            where yIds.Contains(x.Id)
            select x;
```

I don't know whether it will work though - any reason why you don't want to just do a join instead? For instance:

```
var query = from x in dataContext.X
            join y in dataContext.Y.Where(...) on x.Id equals y.Xid
            select x;
```

Comment: There needs to be a "someone else is typing exactly the same answer as you" status popup on this site :)

Comment: Reason to not join: If x is 1 to many with y, the join will give duplicated x's.

Answer (score 8):

To do an IN in sql, you need to use the Contains function in Linq.

So for example:

```
var query = from x in GetX()
            where (from y in GetY() select y.xID).Contains(x.xID)
            select x;
```

You could also define the inner linq query seperately if you like, which is a bit more readable

Comment: What does this mean for performance? Will there be a difference in defining the query contra using it inline?

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a `NOT IN` solution for LINQ to SQL.  Thanks to this question I was able *google* the right thing and find this blog post: [The NOT IN clause in LINQ to SQL](http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

C#

```
NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
var query =
    from c in dc.Customers
    where !(from o in dc.Orders
            select o.CustomerID)
           .Contains(c.CustomerID)
    select c;
```

VB.net

```
Dim db As New NorthwinDataContext()
Dim query = From c In dc.Customers _
            Where Not (From o in dc.Orders _
                       Select o.CustomerID).Contains(c.CustomerID) _
            Select c
```

Comment: this answer helped me a lot, thanks! I have a class setup where one class holds a List(Of Class2) of which each hold a List(Of Class3) (to mimic a container, goods receiving voucher, and goods receiving voucher lines in a warehouse facility). Need to find a way to look for a specific part in Class3 while starting at Class1 without For Each looping through every class instance. This works great (without the Not for me)!